# What is a derivative for the Latin word, liberi (children)?

Tags: derivation

Derivative can be anything for liberi.

Comment: Welcome:  Just a side note to this question: the *lib* is long. All the words in English with a short 'i' (liberty, liberality,) in Latin are **ī** pronounce long "leeb-". And all the words with long 'i' (library, libellous) come from Latin short **ĭ** "lĭb-".  English students of Latin have been known for wrong quantities since 1500.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for words derived from *liberi*, where *liberi* is derived from, or perhaps words derived from the same source as *liberi*? Please [edit your question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/posts/8849/edit) to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

If you are actually looking for words derived **from** *lībĕr,* or *lībĕri, ōrum,* then I suggest you look up all the words beginning with **lib-** in your own language, if that is English, French, Spanish.

If you want words from which *lībĕri, ōrum,* is derived, this may help. It is taken from the Perseus [**Charlton T. Lewis; Charles Short**](http://artflsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/perseus/getobject.pl?c.10:1011.LewisShort18) Latin Dictionary

> ***lībĕri, ōrum,***
>   ***līber, ĕra, ĕrum*** old form, loebesum et loebertatem antiqui dicebant liberum et libertatem. Ita Graeci λοιβὴν et λείβειν, Paul. ex Fest. p. 121 Müll.; cf. 2. Liber), adj. Gr. root λιφ-, λίπτω, to desire; cf. Sanscr. lub-dhas, desirous; Lat. libet, libido,

In Latin children are only *lībĕri* if they are

> "A Free, in a social point of view, not a slave **or**
>   B Free, in a political point of view; said both of a people not under monarchical rule and of one not in subjection to another people"

Otherwise children are *puer* or *juvenis* (from the 15th year); but the same person is often called in one place *adulescens,* and in another *juvenis.*